# When refreshing the sidebar is open on mobile

Tags: reactjs, state, dashboard, sidebar

I have a sidebar menu that has been successfully hidden and shown. When the sidebar menu is hidden and I refresh the page or browser, the hidden sidebar menu will return to its original appearance
How can I avoid this? I want the sidebar open instead on desktop view. It is a dashboard.

This is the ContextProvider.js

```
import { useState, createContext, useContext, useEffect } from "react";

const StateContext = createContext()
const initialState = {
    cart: false,
    notification: false,
    searchBar: false,
}

export const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [activeMenu, setActiveMenu] = useState(true)
    const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(initialState)
    const [screenSize, setScreenSize] = useState(undefined)
    const [currentColor, setCurrentColor] = useState('#bf9a8e')
    const [currentMode, setCurrentMode] = useState('Light')
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
    const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0)

    

    const setMode = (e) => {
        setCurrentMode(e.target.value);
        localStorage.setItem('themeMode', e.target.value);
      };

      const setColor = (color) => {
        setCurrentColor(color);
        localStorage.setItem('colorMode', color);
      };

    const handleClick = (clicked) => {
        setIsClicked({...initialState, [clicked]: true})
    }

    const slideLeft = () => {
        let slider = document.getElementById('slider-2')
        slider.scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft - 500
      }

    const slideRight = () => {
        let slider = document.getElementById('slider-2')
        slider.scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft + 500
      }


    return (
        <StateContext.Provider value={{ 
            activeMenu,
            setActiveMenu,
            isClicked,
            setIsClicked,
            handleClick,
            screenSize,
            setScreenSize, currentColor,
            currentMode,
            setColor,
            setMode,
            isOpen, 
            setIsOpen, 
            slideLeft,
            slideRight,
            currentIndex, 
            setCurrentIndex, 
         }}>
            {children}
        </StateContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const useStateContext = () => useContext(StateContext)
```

I think I should place a useEffect hook to change the initial state but I am not sure if it can solve this issue. This is my sidebar component

```
function Sidebar() {

  const { activeMenu, setActiveMenu, screenSize, currentColor } = useStateContext();

  const handleCloseSideBar = () => {
    if (activeMenu !== undefined && screenSize <= 900) {
      setActiveMenu(false);
    }
  };

  const activeLink = 'flex items-center gap-5 pl-4 pt-3 pb-2.5 text-gray-100 dark:text-white rounded-lg bg-slate-700 text-md m-2'
  const normalLink = 'flex items-center gap-5 pl-4 pt-3 pb-2.5 rounded-lg text-md dark:text-gray-300 text-gray-500 dark:hover:text-gray-600 m-2 hover:bg-gray-200';

  return (
    <div className="mr-4 ml-4 mt-3 scrollbar-hide h-screen md:overflow-hidden overflow-auto md:hover:overflow-auto pb-10">
      {/* LOGO SECTION */}
      {activeMenu && (
        <>
          <div className="flex text-slate-700 dark:text-white justify-between">
            <Link
              to="/"
              onClick={handleCloseSideBar}
              className="flex text-xl font-extrabold items-center gap-3 ml-4 mt-4 tracking-tight"
            >
              <GiPlanetCore/>
              <span>BaIlEyWoRld</span>
            </Link>
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={() => setActiveMenu((prevActiveMenu) => !prevActiveMenu)}
              className="text-2xl p-3 mt-4 block sm:hidden"
            >
              <MdClose />
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="mt-10">
            {links.map((item) => (
              <div key={item.title}>
                <p className="text-gray-400 dark:text-gray-200 font-semibold uppercase m-4 mt-4">
                  {item.title}
                </p>
                {item.links.map((link) => (
                  <NavLink
                    to={`/${link.name}`}
                    key={link.name}
                    onClick={handleCloseSideBar}
                    className={({isActive}) =>
                      isActive ? activeLink : normalLink
                    }
                    style={({isActive}) => ({backgroundColor: isActive ? currentColor : ''})}
                  >
                    {link.icon}
                    <span>{link.name}</span>
                  </NavLink>
                ))}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Sidebar
```

Answer (score 0):

To maintain the state of the sidebar menu being hidden or shown even after a page refresh, you can utilize local storage to store the state information and retrieve it when the page reloads.
Add this in your **Sidebar**

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useStateContext } from "./ContextProvider";


function Sidebar(){
 const { activeMenu, setActiveMenu, screenSize, currentColor, isOpen, setIsOpen } = useStateContext(); 
  
 // handle closing sidebar based on conditions
 const handleCloseSideBar = () => {
   if (activeMenu !== undefined && screenSize <= 900) {
    setActiveMenu(false);
    setIsOpen(false);
   }
 };
  
 // handle opening sidebar based on conditions
 const handleOpenSideBar = () => {
  if (activeMenu !== undefined && screenSize <= 900) {
   setActiveMenu(true);
   setIsOpen(true);
  }
 };

 useEffect(() => {
  const storedIsOpen = localStorage.getItem("sidebarOpen");
  if (storedIsOpen !== null) {
   setIsOpen(storedIsOpen === "true");
  }
 }, [setIsOpen]);
 
 // and here add other parts of your component remain unchanged

}
```

Comment: I did it but now I have this issue useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the useEffect hook in your ContextProvider.js file to store the state in localStorage whenever it changes and retrieve it when the component mounts.

```
export const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  // ... (other state variables and functions)

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedIsOpen = localStorage.getItem('isOpen');

    if (storedIsOpen !== null) {
      setIsOpen(JSON.parse(storedIsOpen));
    } else {
      setIsOpen(screenSize <= 900); // Adjust the threshold as needed
    }
  }, [screenSize]);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('isOpen', JSON.stringify(isOpen));
  }, [isOpen]);

  // ... (rest of the component)
};
```

**"whenever the isOpen state changes, it will be stored in localStorage. And when the component mounts, it will check if there is a stored value and set the state accordingly"**

Comment: Now it is working on mobile view but is closed on desktop. I added this logic in the contextprovider

Comment: it might be due to the initial state of isOpen being set to false, I have update my code try this one

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it in the mobile view this way in the contextprovider

```
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem('activeMenu', JSON.stringify(activeMenu));
}, [activeMenu]);

useEffect(() => {
  const storedActiveMenu = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('activeMenu'));
  setActiveMenu(storedActiveMenu || false);
}, []);
```

Comment: But now in desktop view the sidebar is not visible. It is driving me mad lol

Comment: The variable that affects the sidebar is activeMenu not isOpen

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).